# Reading wave header c++

Tags: c++, wav

So im trying to read the header of a wav file and for some reason i can only read parts of it.

Im using this structure to store the data :

```
struct WaveHeaderType
{
    char chunkId[4];
    unsigned long chunkSize;
    char format[4];
    char subChunkId[4];
    unsigned long subChunkSize;
    unsigned short audioFormat;
    unsigned short numChannels;
    unsigned long sampleRate;
    unsigned long bytesPerSecond;
    unsigned short blockAlign;
    unsigned short bitsPerSample;
    char dataChunkId[4];
    unsigned long dataSize;
};
```

and this code to read the file:

```
WaveHeaderType waveFileHeader;

fread(&waveFileHeader, sizeof(waveFileHeader), 1, filePtr);
```

and after this only the chunkId,chunkSize,format and subChunkId  have values, the rest is just null. What am i doing wrong? or do i just happen to have a corrupted wav file? (i can play the wav file in kmplayer without problems)

Comment: You did open the file in binary mode, didn't you?

Answer (score 4):

```
fread(&waveFileHeader, sizeof(waveFileHeader), 1, filePtr);
```

is probably what you meant. With & it will be size of a pointer, so you read just 4 or 8 bytes.

Also consider using some kind of #pragma pack on the structure unless you have it from an official header, pading between members may result a different layout as in the file.

Comment: I dont know how that got there, wasn't supposed to be a pointer. But that doesnt solve the problem at all. (The pointer was from one earlier version with which i tried to mess up a little, but that was indeed wrong direction)

Answer (score 2):

instead of `sizeof(&waveFileHeader)` you need to write `sizeof(waveFileHeader)`

`sizeof(&waveFileHeader)` gives a constant 4 bytes (pointer size) in a 32 bit system.

`sizeof(waveFileHeader)` gives the byte size of `waveFileHeader` struct

Comment: I dont know how that got there, wasn't supposed to be a pointer. But that doesnt solve the problem at all. (The pointer was from one earlier version with which i tried to mess up a little, but that was indeed wrong direction)

Answer (score 0):

You want to read the size of your struct which is `sizeof(waveFileHeader)`.

With the `&` you'll reading the size of element pointing towards a waveFileHeader.

try:

```
fread(&waveFileHeader, sizeof(waveFileHeader), 1, filePtr);
```

Comment: I dont know how that got there, wasn't supposed to be a pointer. But that doesnt solve the problem at all. (The pointer was from one earlier version with which i tried to mess up a little, but that was indeed wrong direction)

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the above noted "taking the size of a pointer is not the same as the size of a structure", I worry a lot when I see `unsigned long` in a datastructure supposed to be stored in a file (or read from a file). This is exactly the type of thing that goes wrong when moving code from a 32 to a 64 bit environment (or when moving from one compiler to another, or using the same compiler, but on a different processor type).

You should be using size-defined types, such as `uint8_t`, `uint16_t`, `uint32_t`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a fixed struct such as you are doing can work for many WAV files, but there could be additional elements within the file header and some of the fields can be of varying size. There is a family of API functions starting with mmioOpen that you can use instead to parse the file, illustrated here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743664(v=vs.85).aspx